# What should be provided as parameter to check which enum name occured

Tags: c#, enums

If I loop through list containing names like Enum:

```
newEnum.ForEach(x => {
    if(x == Enum.AAA) { method(parameter); }
    else if(x == Enum.BBB) { method(parameter); }
    // etc.
});

method(parameter);
```

so when defining a method to do something, I dont want to write It 10 times,
so how should I provide parameter in the method so I can check which of this 
enum occured ? Enum.AAA or Enum.BBB or something else ?

---

EDIT: How to provide information on selected enum in method so I can use it. I need to do something depending on is it Enum.AAA, or Enum.BBB, or maybe some other? hope you understand me

Comment: You can write a method accepting an integer instead of an enum. However you have to verify if the provided value has a valid name anyway.

Comment: Can you please provide real code and don't omit relevant informations like types?

Comment: What is `parameter`? It´s hard to understand what you want to achieve from this short piece of - what is this, pseudocode?

Comment: If `Enum` is for example `public enum MyFirstEnum{ Item1, Item2 }` this method should accept `MyFirstEnum` as parameter-type.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Probably, but either way `parameter` must be declared as *something* common between `MyFirstEnum` and `MySecondEnum`, shouldn´t it?

Comment: Please provide a clean sample code which can be compiled. It is unclear!

Comment: @HimBromBeere: OP hasnt mentioned two different enum-types. He always uses `Enum`, `Enum.AAA` and `Enum.BBB`. So the parameter just needs to be `Enum`. The method itself can use an `if` or `switch` then.

Comment: You still have to make some kind of connection between enum and a method to call. So basically you can use a dictionary to tighten them up together and just use your enum value as a key value.

Comment: @m.rogalski: he wants to avoid multiple methods

Comment: @HimBromBeere I would write something else instead of parameter if I knew what should be there. That was part of the question. 
I asked the question to the best of my possibilities..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't mentioned two different enum-types and always use `Enum`, `Enum.AAA` and `Enum.BBB`, the parameter just needs to be of type `Enum`. The method can use a `switch` then.

```
public enum Enum{ AAA, BBB }
```

...

```
foreach(Enum x in newEnum)
    method(x);
```

....

```
public void method(Enum x)
{
    switch(x)
    {
         case Enum.AAA: ... break;
         case Enum.BBB: ... break;
    }
}
```

Comment: thats exactly what i was asking for :) i have to say thank you even its not welcomed on SO as i dont have reputation for upvote :)